# Parameter passing from one XMLview(list) to another XMLview(list) on SAPUI5

Tags: sapui5

I'm new to SAPUI5, seeking your advice to resolve one issue. my requirement is like this:

> 1st page shows list on XMLview on product. 
>   2nd page shows list on XMLview on storage bin for this product in the warehouse. 
>   3rd page then show the details of storage bin.

I created one oDATA, two entities types : Product and Bin, both have GetEntitySet implemented, I think the oDATA result is fine. My problem is on the 2nd XMLview page where I have hard time to set the items on sap.m.list... my XML looks like this below, problem is that all hardcoded, what I tried to achieve is to pass the value from 1st page on product/plant/warehouse... Please advise how can I resolve this dynamically value assignment. much appreciated.

```
<Page
    title="Warehouse Storage Bin List"
    showNavButton="true"
    navButtonPress="handleNavButtonPress" >

    <List items="{/Bin?$filter=Lgnum eq 'XXX'  and Matnr eq 'XXXXXX' and Werks eq 'XXXX'}">
        <ObjectListItem type="Active" 
         press="handleListItemPress" 
         title="{StgeBin}" intro="{StgeType}" number="{Stock}" 
         numberUnit="">
            <attributes ObjectAttribute=""></attributes>
        </ObjectListItem>
    </List>

 </Page>
```

BR,J

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you already know how to navigate between Pages in sap.m. If not this is the main method you are searching for (using `sap.m.App`, there are more if you use `sap.m.SplitApp`):

```
to(sPageId, sTransitionName, oData, oTransitionParameters)
```

Notice the parameter `oData` -
This optional object can carry any payload data which should be made available to the target page. The "beforeShow" event on the target page will contain this data object as "data" property.

So assuming you use a sap.m.List on your first view to trigger navigation to the second. It could look like this:

View1.view.xml

```
<Page title="Products">
    <List items="{/Products}" selectionChange="onSelectionChange">
        <StandardListItem title="{title}" />
    </List>
</Page>
```

View1.controller.js

```
onSelectionChange : function(oEv) {
  var oItem = oEv.getParameter("listItem");
  var oApp = // get your App
  // Binding path will be something like "/Products/4" (fifth item selected)
  oApp.to("view2", "slide", { path : oItem.getBindingContextPath() })
}
```

View2.controller.js

```
onInit : function() {
  var self = this;
  this.getView().addEventDelegate({
    onBeforeShow: function(oEv) {
      var detailBindingPath = oEv.data.path;
      // establish view2 bindings based on the selected binding path
      var oList = self.getView().byId("List");
      oList.bindItems(detailBindingPath +"/Bin", <YOUR_TEMPLATE>, null, [
        new sap.ui.model.Filter("Lgnum", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.EQ, 'XXX'),
        new sap.ui.model.Filter("Matnr", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.EQ, 'XXXXXX'),
        new sap.ui.model.Filter("Werks", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.EQ, 'XXXX') 
      ]);
    }
  });
}
```

You will have to establish your bindings in code since you don't know the binding path during view creation.

Hope I got what you were trying to do. Didn't run the code so let me know if you face issues.

BR
Chris

Comment: Thanks Chris. I followed the steps you listed. I agree with your approach, however, in the View2.controller.js onBeforeShow... I don't get detailBindingPath ( not available in debug ), and "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function" in the var oList xxxxx line. not sure if I missed anything. I tried a different way to get value... none seems working. thanks for your help again.

Comment: I adapted the onInit a bit in my answer. You have to get 'this' into the anonymous functions context (var self = this;). How does oEv look like?

Comment: Thanks Chris, I got this part working by using the oEv. am now in that bindings, thanks for your great help.

Comment: Hello Chris, adding more to here... in my case, I'm using 1st page for LIST of product, 2nd page for LIST of storage bins based on the product selected on page 1, then get all the bins out. so your beforeshow oList.bindItems need some more advice... I have to use the url/Bin?$filter to make it working. what do you suggest to put in my xml view for list items =??? do I put in /Bin or empty or sth else... this seems my last block. thanks again

Comment: Sorry, need to add a line missed ... in debug that bindItem, it giving out error => Uncaught Error: Missing template or factory function for aggregation items of Element sap.m.List#Bin--List ! .. my code is like this ( hardcode for now ) oList.bindItems("/Bin?$filter=Lgnum eq 'XXX' and Matnr eq 'XXXXXX' and Werks eq 'XXXX' "); Hello Chris, appreciated.

Comment: @Jeff extended my sample with template and filters. Appreciate an upvote ;)

Comment: Thanks Chris, looks like I have to come back again to do vote up, my user is so new that need more point to click that vote up. will recheck once it has enough power. thanks a lot